# Getting an array from pointer in a structure

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a structure like this

```
struct quantum_reg_struct
{
  int width;    /* number of qubits in the qureg */
  int size;     /* number of non-zero vectors */
  int hashw;    /* width of the hash array */
  COMPLEX_FLOAT *amplitude;
};

typedef struct quantum_reg_struct quantum_reg;

quantum_reg reg;
```

If *amplitude is pointing to the start of array of type COMPLEX_FLOAT then I want to be able to store this in a an array of type Complex_float. Is it possible for me?

Secondly I need to understand the usage of -> operator. What happens if something like this is written .

```
reg->amplitude[1] *= -1;
```

Comment: Is COMPLEX_FLOAT a structure? If so then allocate memory to it -> operator us used to access structure members using a pointer variable.

Comment: `amplitude` is pointing. Not `*amplitude`.

Comment: Please, only _one question per question_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is, your code would crash if you accessed amplitude without assigning it to point to memory.

```
quantum_reg reg;
reg.amplitude = malloc(5 * sizeof (COMPLEX_FLOAT));
reg.amplitude[0] = 1.2f;  // I'm guessing COMPLEX_FLOAT is just a typedef'd float for this to work 
reg.amplitude[1] = 1.5f;
// reg->amplitude won't compile because reg is not a pointer.
// if COMPLEX_FLOAT is a struct, then reg.amplitude->fieldname could work, where fieldname is something in COMPLEX_FLOAT.
free(reg.amplitude); // free the allocated memory.
```

If amplitude has a fixed number of elements, consider redefining it as an array, e.g. `COMPLEX_FLOAT amplitude[5];`. This is easier to use because you don't have to worry about `malloc` and `free`. The advantage of malloc and free is that you can pick the size (number of elements) at runtime, but if you don't need this, then stick with an array.

Comment: Yes,COMPLEX_FLOAT is a typedef for float. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. In this line.        reg.amplitude = malloc(5 * sizeof (COMPLEX_FLOAT))   is 5 here for some reason or is it just an arbitrary example

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could doing something like this :

```
quantum_reg.amplitude = malloc(sizeof(*quantum_reg.amplitude) * n);
```

Now the -> operator is just a shortcut for

```
(*reg).amplitude
```

Comment: You're proposing a memory leak... maybe. Depends what the OP started off with. The question is unclear.

Comment: I just did not mention the free part as it was not the purpose of the question. We are not doing a course on how/where/when to free the memory

Comment: Is that supposed to be a joke?!